# What is the type of the objects returned by ISelectionContainer.GetObjects?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, vsix

I'm writing an extension for VS2010, and my package implements `IVsSelectionEvents` to track the selection in the solution explorer:

```
    public int OnSelectionChanged(
        IVsHierarchy pHierOld,
        uint itemidOld,
        IVsMultiItemSelect pMISOld,
        ISelectionContainer pSCOld,
        IVsHierarchy pHierNew,
        uint itemidNew,
        IVsMultiItemSelect pMISNew,
        ISelectionContainer pSCNew)
    {
        if (pSCNew != null)
        {
            uint count;
            pSCNew.CountObjects((uint) Constants.GETOBJS_SELECTED, out count);
            object[] selectedObjects = new object[count];
            pSCNew.GetObjects((uint) Constants.GETOBJS_SELECTED, count, selectedObjects);

            // What is the type of this object?
            var selectedItem = selectedObjects[0] as ???;

        }
        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }
```

`GetObjects` fills an array of objects, but **I don't know what is the actual type of these objects**. `GetType` returns `System.__ComObject`, which is not very helpful. I assume these objects implement a known interface, but how do I know which one? This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere... Currently I'm using `dynamic` to access the properties of the object, but it's not ideal, and anyway I don't know which methods are exposed by this object (I can only see the properties in the Watch window)

Does anyone know **which interface is implemented by project items in the solution explorer**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so it seems that the items returned by GetObjects are of type [`FileProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vslangproj.fileproperties.aspx). But anyway, I found a much easier approach, using EnvDTE instead... An [`EnvDTE.ProjectItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitem.aspx) object can be retrieved from the hierarchy and item id with this method:

```
    private static ProjectItem GetProjectItem(IVsHierarchy hierarchy, uint itemId)
    {
        object o;
        if (hierarchy.GetProperty(itemId, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ExtObject, out o) == VSConstants.S_OK)
        {
            return o as ProjectItem;
        }
        return null;
    }
```